ASP.NET Core AddJwtBearer TimeProvider: TimeTravel proof Token Verification
We're trying to speed up some integration tests (.NET 8) by jumping into the future (by using our IClock abstraction).
This by itself works fine, but after creating a new JWT token, which also has correct timestamps, the verification fails with

www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token",error_description="The token is not valid before '07/26/2024 17:56:05'"

So it looks like the auth middleware is still using system time, which is kind of odd because we passed our timeprovider to AddJwtBearer:
services.AddSingleton<IClock>(ClockMutable.Default);

services
    .AddAuthentication()
    .AddJwtBearer(AuthenticationSchemes.Default, c => {
        ...
        c.TimeProvider = ClockMutable.Default;
        ...
    });

Also none of the members of the ClockMutable.Default instance are called.
What do I need to do so AddJwtBearer uses the provided TimeProvider?
Edit 3
Digging a bit further it looks like it just isn't implemented yet:
https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/pull/2612
Edit 2:
Working example of the Problem I'm having. Just create a WebApi Project, add the "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Package and replace Program.cs with the following:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;

var secretKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("SomeSuperLongSecretSomeSuperLongSecretSomeSuperLongSecretSomeSuperLongSecret");
TimeProviderSettable.Value = new DateTimeOffset(2025, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.Zero);
TimeProvider clock = new TimeProviderSettable();

//clock = TimeProvider.System;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(cfg => {
    cfg.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    cfg.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    cfg.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(x => {
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    x.SaveToken = false;
    x.TimeProvider = clock;
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true, IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(secretKey),
        ValidateIssuer = false, ValidateAudience = false, ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    };
});

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapGet("/protected", () => "Success").RequireAuthorization();
app.MapGet("/weatherforecast", async () => {
    var token = GenerateJWTToken();

    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
    var resp = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:5054/protected");

    return resp;
});

app.Run();

string GenerateJWTToken() {
    var jwtToken = new JwtSecurityToken(
        claims: [new(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "1"), new(ClaimTypes.Name, "UserName")],
        notBefore: clock.GetUtcNow().UtcDateTime,
        expires: clock.GetUtcNow().UtcDateTime.AddMinutes(30),
        signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(secretKey), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
    );
    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwtToken);
}

class TimeProviderSettable : TimeProvider { public static DateTimeOffset Value { get; set; } public override DateTimeOffset GetUtcNow() => Value; }

When the "/weatherforecast" endpoint is called, the request to "/protected" fails.
The failure is logged with:
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[1]
      Failed to validate the token.
      Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenNotYetValidException: IDX10222: Lifetime validation failed. The token is not yet valid. ValidFrom (UTC): '2025-01-01 00:00:00', Current time (UTC): '2024-07-27 14:18:40'.

Since I passed the TimeProvider instance to the AddJwtBearer call, my epectation is that it should use the instance to get the "current" time and do the verification with it. But as one can see, the log message states "Current time (UTC): '2024-07-27 14:18:40'".
Edit:
IClock Implementation
public class ClockMutable : TimeProvider, IClock {
    public static ClockMutable Default { get; } = new ClockMutable();

    private DateTimeOffset? stoppedOn;
    private TimeSpan offset;

    public DateTimeOffset Now => (stoppedOn != null ? stoppedOn.Value.ToLocalTime() : DateTimeOffset.Now) + offset;
    public DateTimeOffset UtcNow => (stoppedOn != null ? stoppedOn.Value : DateTimeOffset.UtcNow) + offset;
    public DateTime UtcDateTime => DateTime.UtcNow;

    public void Resume() {
        if(stoppedOn == null) return;
        offset += stoppedOn.Value - DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
        stoppedOn = null;
    }

    public void Pause() {
        if(stoppedOn != null) return;
        stoppedOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
    }

    public void SkipForward(TimeSpan delta) {
        if(delta < TimeSpan.Zero) throw new Exception();
        offset += delta;
    }
    public void Set(DateTimeOffset future) {
        if(future < UtcNow) throw new Exception();
        offset = TimeSpan.Zero;
        stoppedOn = future;
    }

    public void Reset() {
        stoppedOn = null;
        offset = TimeSpan.Zero;
    }

    public override DateTimeOffset GetUtcNow() => UtcNow;
}


Does the TimeSpan configured, how is your IClock implementation?

I don't think the problem is the IClock implementation since none of its members are called but I've added it anyway. What do you mean by "TimeSpan configured"?

Update
After some research , you might consider the custom token validation as a workaround as the server time system may not editable through your client configuration.

Since the instance is not called, it might be the issue of registered service not persist in your provider. Here I have a workaround.
1.Register the instance one more time in IntegrationTestFixture.cs
public class IntegrationTestFixture : IDisposable
{
    public ServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; private set; }
    public MockClock MockClock { get; private set; }

    public IntegrationTestFixture()
    {
        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

        // Register the instance here
        var initialTime = new DateTime(2024, 7, 30);
        MockClock = new MockClock(initialTime);

        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.Development.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .Build();

        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(configuration);

        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IClock>(MockClock);
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<TimeProvider>(new CustomTimeProvider(MockClock));
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<TokenService>();
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<MyService>();

        ServiceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (ServiceProvider is IDisposable disposable)
        {
            disposable.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

2. Then in the test MyServiceIntegrationTests.cs the token validates on the mocked time.
    public class MyServiceIntegrationTests : 
        IClassFixture<IntegrationTestFixture>
    {
    private readonly IntegrationTestFixture _fixture;

    public MyServiceIntegrationTests(IntegrationTestFixture fixture)
    {
        _fixture = fixture;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test_DoSomething()
    {
        var tokenService = _fixture.ServiceProvider.GetService<TokenService>();
        if (tokenService == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to retrieve TokenService from service provider.");

        var token = tokenService.GenerateToken();

        // Act
        // Simulate advancing time to check if the token will be valid after a certain time
        _fixture.MockClock.Advance(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15));
        var isTokenValidAfter15Minutes = tokenService.ValidateToken(token);

        _fixture.MockClock.Advance(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20));
        var isTokenValidAfter35Minutes = tokenService.ValidateToken(token); // token should now be expired

        // Assert
        Assert.True(isTokenValidAfter15Minutes);
        Assert.False(isTokenValidAfter35Minutes);
    }
    }




I couldn't get your workaround to work. I edited my post to inclue a minimal example. Could you add your changes there?

@Arokh I can reproduce your issue exactly the same with your code. I did a further research  based on your doc link and from my opinion, the issue is when acting the authorization of JWT, the server time system cannot be mocked by your client TimeProvider, which is easy to understand. And I tested with the FakeTimeProvider, which won't work. My previous answer using the validation directly validate the date contained in the token, so it didn't catch the error.
